# php mail script that allows user to define the target address the email will be sent to

Tags: php

OK, so I've got a basic form and email script that I wrote for for a website contact form. 
For another purpose, I would like to modify this script to, from the contact form, allow the user to define where the email will be sent to. I've tried several methods out there and haven't had any luck.

HTML:

```
<form action='/mail.php' id='contact-form' method='post'>
  <p>
    <label for='cf_name'>Name to send emails as *</label>
      <input id='cf_name' name='cf_name' placeholder='Enter your "name"...' required='required' title='Name' type='text' />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for='cf_email'>Email address to be sent to *</label>
      <input id='cf_email' name='cf_email' placeholder='Email address...' required='required' title='Email address' type='email' />
  </p>
  <p>
  <label for='cf_subject'>Message Title *</label>
    <input id='cf_subject' name='cf_subject' placeholder='Email Subject...' required='required' title='Email Subject' type='text' />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for='cf_message'>Message *</label>
      <textarea id='cf_message' name='cf_message' placeholder='Message text...' required='required' rows='10' title='Message text'></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type='submit' value='Send message' />
  </p>
</form>
```

And the current semi-edited PHP:

```
<?php

// Destination email address
define('EMAIL_DEST', 'abc@123.com');

// Contact form error message
define('ERROR_MESSAGE', 'Something went wrong, please try to submit later.');

// Contact form message title
define('CONTACT_EMAIL_TITLE', '');

// Contact form success message
define('CONTACT_SUCCESS_MESSAGE', 'Thank you! We will get back to you as soon as possible.');


// Variables assignment
$name         = isset($_POST['cf_name']) ? $_POST['cf_name'] : '';
$email        = isset($_POST['cf_email']) ? $_POST['cf_email'] : '';
$subject      = isset($_POST['cf_subject']) ? $_POST['cf_subject'] : '';
$message      = isset($_POST['cf_message']) ? $_POST['cf_message'] : '';


// Send email if required fields are filled
if(!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($subject) && !empty($message)) {
    // Headers
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: ' . $name;

// Message title
$message_title = CONTACT_EMAIL_TITLE;

// Message
$message_body = "$message";

// Send mail
mail(EMAIL_DEST, $message_title, $message_body, $headers);


// Show success message
echo '<div class="box-success round-3"><div class="box-content"><p>' . CONTACT_SUCCESS_MESSAGE . '</p></div></div>';
exit;
} else {
    // Show error message
    echo '<div class="box-error round-3"><div class="box-content"><p>' . ERROR_MESSAGE . '</p></div></div>';
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Well the way I would do it is, to have an input box where the person would enter an Email address, make sure it's valid then, assign that variable as the `to:` or `cc:` or `bcc:` - thus `$send_to=$_POST['send_to'];` then use that to send as your recipient. The input would be `<input type="text" name="send_to">`

Comment: You can send the same message to multiple people by seperating them with a comma, or set up another `mail()` function such as `mail($send_to, $message_title_cc, $message_body_cc, $headers_cc);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining

```
/ Destination email address
define('EMAIL_DEST', 'abc@123.com');
```

and then send the email to this adress via :

```
// Send mail
mail(EMAIL_DEST, $message_title, $message_body, $headers);
```

So if you want to send the email to the provided email adress just use

```
// Send mail
mail($email, $message_title, $message_body, $headers);
```

Because the email adress is already defined:

```
$email = isset($_POST['cf_email']) ? $_POST['cf_email'] : '';
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much! I thought I had tried some variation of this in the beginning, but I must have missed a character somewhere or misspelled, who know. Anyways, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what is EMAIL_DEST here..You must have defined it somewhere .

if you look at mail function

```
bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

the first string is for `to` here,

so, i am pretty sure you need to add $email instead of EMAIL_DEST in mail function, to send it to that particular user

```
 mail($email , $message_title, $message_body, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with your `Mail Header`

```
// Headers
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: ' . $email;
```

The `From` in your `Mail Header` should be an email address rather than of name.

Or you can specify the name if you like in this way

```
$headers .= 'From: ' . $name . '<' .$email. '>'; //From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>
```

**EDIT**

BUT You also need to specify the `$to` parameter in the `mail` function like other says

```
mail($email , $subject, $message, $headers);
```